# Swift: Dictionary of Dicitionaries, cannot get subscript

Tags: swift, dictionary, subscript

I've looked at other subscript issues here and I don't think they match my problem. I have a dictionary of dictionaries - `Dictionary[String:Dictionary[String:String]]`

In an extension I want to loop through all the values (Dictionary[String:String] and retrieve one of the values.

So I wrote this:

```
for dictNEO in Array(self.values)  {
    print(dictNEO)
    print(type(of: dictNEO))
    print(dictNEO["approachDate"])
}
```

and am getting this error on the last print line: `Value of type 'Value' has no subscripts`

Here's the first two print lines:

```
["nominalDist": "\"13.58 ", "approachDate": "\"2020-Feb-01 08:18 ± < 00:01\"", "minimumDist": "\"13.58 ", "diameter": "\"92 m -  210 m\"", "name": "\"(2017 AE5)\""]
Dictionary<String, String>
```

So I am confused as to why it is telling me it has no subscripts when it sees the type of as a Dictionary.

Comment: Could you edit your question and elaborate on "in an extension" – show how you specify the extension. Also what version of Swift are you trying this with? That should help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have written this as an extension to Dictionary if I understand you correctly and that means that `self` is generic and defined as `Dictionary<Key, Value>` and not to you specific type so in your `for` loop you are looping over an array of [Value].

So you need to typecast `Value` before accessing it as a dictionary

```
if let dictionary = dictNEO as? [String: String] {
    print(dictNEO["approachDate"])
}
```

but since it makes little sense to have an extension to `Dictionary` where you access a specific key it would be better to write it as a function. Since the dictionary is well defined now there is no issue with the last `print`

```
func printValuesForSubKey(_ key: String,  _ dict: [String: [String: String]]) {
    for (dictNEO) in dict.values {
        print(dictNEO)
        print(type(of: dictNEO))
        print(dictNEO[key])        
    }
}
```

Note, I don't have an explanation why `type(of:)` recognises it as `[String: String]`

Comment: Regarding the last remark: the difference between what is known at compile time and the actual type at runtime would explain this.

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet doesn't work because `values` property is a collection of collections and with `Array(values)` you create a collection of collection of collections. In short, instead going down the code goes up and creates new collection level.

- Solution with a [Higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) `map`:

  ```
  self.values.map { print(type(of: $0)); $0["approachDate"] }
  ```
- Solution with [For-In Loop](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)

  ```
  for dictNEO in self.values  {
      print(dictNEO)
      print(type(of: dictNEO))
      print(dictNEO["approachDate"])
  }
  ```

Comment: While this code might work does it answer "So I am confused as to why it is telling me it has no subscripts when it sees the type of as a Dictionary"? You might wish to edit your answer and say why your version works and the original does not.

Comment: The type of `dictNEO` is (or should be) `Array<[String : String]>`, there is no "collection of collection of collections" etc.

Comment: copy paste a result of print(type(of: values)) before For-in Loop

Comment: That's how I got the type, I copied if from a playground, otherwise I'd have written `[[String : String]]` ;-) See Joakim Danielson answer for the diagnosis.

Comment: So, copy & past here more code: the class and a playground snippet